# How can I add "pyspark" to "Jupyter-Notebook"'s File->New Notebook menu?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am very new in Spark. I have installed Spark and could run the following test code successfully:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql('''select 'spark' as hello ''')
df.show()
```

But I can't see `pyspark` in `File -> New Notebook` menu. How can I add it to the menu? (I use Windows machine but don't use Anaconda).

Please let me know if I should add more information.

Answer (score 0):

A notebook creates just that. You select a kernel within the notebook...

You would need to create a *new*  Jupyter kernel with the necessary environment variables.

In the past, I used [Apache Toree](https://toree.apache.org/docs/current/user/installation/) for this.

However, `findspark` already does most of the work for you and is portable across development environments. (For instance, Pycharm is far more feature rich than Jupyter)

Comment: Related - https://anchormen.nl/blog/big-data-services/pyspark-jupyter-kernels/